# Php Remove page from existing pdf file

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, fpdi

What is the easiest way to remove one page (ie. the last page) from a local pdf file using php? I have around 100 files, and each one needs to have its last page dropped. Optimally, I want to replace the file with a file of the same name that is just one page shorter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/)

Example:

```
pdf = new FPDI();
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile('document.pdf');

//  Array of pages to skip -- modify this to fit your needs
$skipPages = [3,15,17,22];

//  Add all pages of source to new document
for( $pageNo=1; $pageNo<=$pageCount; $pageNo++ )
{
    //  Skip undesired pages
    if( in_array($pageNo,$skipPages) )
        continue;

    //  Add page to the document
    $templateID = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);
    $pdf->getTemplateSize($templateID);
    $pdf->addPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($templateID);
}

$pdf->Output();
```

You can delete de last page using the array size easily.

Comment: Using this, the output PDF dimensions may be wrong. To ensure correct width and height, replace the `getTemplateSize` row with this: `$size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($templateID);` Replace the `addPage` row with this: `$pdf->addPage($size['orientation'], [$size[0], $size[1]]);`